# How to download unsupported files from the default browser?

Tags: browser, downloading

When I try to download an SVG through the default browser (eg, by clicking on the image on [a Wikipedia illustration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aIndoEuropeanTree.svg) - despite the .svg extension, that page is actually showing a PNG preview), the 'Downloads' says, 'Cannot download. The content is not supported on the phone'.

I tried installing [a SVG editor](http://www.appbrain.com/app/maplepaint/com.mapleworks), thinking then the phone would figure out I could view SVGs, but no luck.

[ETA: Is it a mistake by this program that it hasn't registered itself on my phone as a .svg handler?]

Luckily [Firefox](http://www.appbrain.com/app/mozilla-firefox-web-browser/org.mozilla.firefox) displays SVGs natively, but still, there should be a way to download files even if the phone "thinks" it can't display it! Any ideas?

Running Froyo on Samsung Galaxy S.

Comment: related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6984/how-to-download-files-from-the-web-in-the-android-browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Download Crutch](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.org-ouroborus-android-downloadcrutch-jjz.aspx) registers itself as a handler for all files, letting you download any file type.  Download it on a PC and save to your SD card, then install from your phone.  Third-party sources must be enabled in `Settings -> Applications`.

Comment: Hm, do you know why it's not in the Market? Seems a bit weird.

Comment: @pfctdayelise I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Some file managers such as "Astro" will optionally register themselves to handle arbitrary files for the web browser - but there may (still?) be a warning about this breaking attachment preview in gmail.

There there's always the copy the url to clipboard, open a terminal, and paste it into wget, perhaps inside single quotes...

Answer (score 0):

The stock browser on Android gingerbread, Ice cream Sandwish (and possibly other versions) has this limitation (see [resource `download_not_acceptable`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser/blob/gingerbread-release/res/values/strings.xml)).

It is possible to download more file types with a an alternative browser (ex: Opera mobile) or a download manager.