# How to download a Windows executable?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, downloading, stock-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to download unsupported files from the default browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9361/how-to-download-unsupported-files-from-the-default-browser)

When I try to download a Windows executable (`.exe`) from Android browser, the download starts but stops immediately with error

> Cannot download. The content is not supported on this phone.

I don't want to support the content, I just want to download the file and save it on the SD card so that I can get it on my desktop computer (which has no internet connection)

Any suggestion?

Comment: Strange. I can download .exe files on my mobile (Gingerbread 2.3) using the stock browser -- just checked. Would it be possible for you to post a link to what you are trying to download?

Comment: I'm trying to download the JDK http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u31-download-1501634.html (click accept and then Win32 version)

Comment: I have a Samsung Galaxy S2, and I am wondering whether it is really the stock browser...

Comment: Just tried. Download has started normally, I'll cancel because it's too big. But it seems to work properly. I guess you should mention what device you have, so that others can test.

Comment: @MartinTapankov Sorry for the confusion, samsung Galaxy is on Android 2.3, not Android 3.2!

Comment: I don't think it is specific to Samsung Galaxy S II: I have found this string in `strings.xml` in Android source code.

Comment: Hmmm, you may be on to something, I have CyanogenMod 7.1, and maybe they made modifications to the stock browser to remove this restriction.

Answer (score 3):

The stock browser on Android gingerbread has this limitation (see [resource `download_not_acceptable`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser/blob/gingerbread-release/res/values/strings.xml)).

It is possible to download more file types with a an alternative browser (ex: Opera mobile) or a download manager.

Comment: This is a good idea, consider adding it as an answer to the marked duplicate -- a valid way to double up on the rep ;)