# Cannot download APK file on my phone

Tags: applications

I want to try out my app with the apk-file of my bin-Directory.I sent the apk per mail. I can download and install it on my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab3 Lite) without Problems. But my Smartphone (Samsung Galaxy S Plus i9001) can't download it "Download failed". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: arcor. I should try it with another one?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the apk from email using a browser like Chrome or Firefox? What are your results?

Comment: If you're developing anyhow, why not simply using `adb install` while the device is connected? Alternatively, copy the file to your device's SD card should do fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Compress your apk file with winrar or 7zip, send it trough the mail, download it on your phone and the uncompress it on your phone.

Or use teamviewer quicksupport, personally I recommend this.

Comment: Any reasoning for such answer. It is not mentioned in the question that the apk is been detected as some sort of potential malware, neither it has been mentioned that files with other file type are getting downloaded easily.

Comment: As you said he didn't say if it was detected as a malware or he didn't say it's working with other file types.  So do what I said and then narrow the possible causes.

Comment: Don't OEM Android ROMs have built-in protection against receiving APKs either through Bluetooth or the stock browser?

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to enable third-party sources or to install a handler for "unknown" file types.  My answer from [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/9376/1465) has more details:

> [Download Crutch](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.org-ouroborus-android-downloadcrutch-jjz.aspx) registers itself as a handler for all files, letting you download any file type.  Download it on a PC and save to your SD card, then install from your phone.  Third-party sources must be enabled in `Settings -> Applications`.